# i want to add data of two column in one column in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a table with three columns:
One for **serial no**, second for **id**, and third for **result**.

```
**sr**
1
2
3
4
5

**id**
10
20
30
40
50
```

and the first two columns compose the third column **Result**.

I want to achieve the following output:

```
**Result**
1
10
2
20
3
30
4
40
5
50
```

Is it possible to get such output in data `GridView` of c# windows application?

OR

I have tally data, ledger names and group name, and I want to get ledger name and group name in one column according to group category.

Suppose the group name is Tax Revenue and under that I have the list of ledgers:

```
Tax Revenue
    LedName1
    LedName2
    LedName3
    LedName4
Revenue Receipts
    LedName1
    LedName2
    LedName3
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use SQL to retrieve data? Because in this case you can simply make a query this way:

```
select result from (
select 'A' as tableID, serialno as result From MyTable
union
select 'B' as tableID, id as result From MyTable
) as x
order by result,tableid
```

If you have arrays or list you can use Linq to query this structs similar way.

Comment: Yes. I use the sql query to get data using odbc connection. From my above second example Tax Revenue, Revenue Receipts is have another table and LedName have other table. combining both table data i wish to represent output in data grid view.

Answer (score 0):

Make each data-point a class

```
public class DataPoint
{
    public int sr {get; internal set;}
    public int id {get; internal set;}
    public int Result {get {return sr * id;}}
    public DataPoint (int sr, int id)
    {
        this.sr = sr;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

ObservableCollection<DataPoint> MyData = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>();
MyData.Add (new DataPoint(1, 10));
MyData.Add (new DataPoint(2, 20));
MyData.Add (new DataPoint(3, 30));
MyData.Add (new DataPoint(4, 40));
MyData.Add (new DataPoint(5, 50));
```

MyData should be assignable as DataSource to a GridView. (Not compile-tested, it shows the general idea. If data should be changeable dynamically, MyData needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged). Also, rows will sometimes appear in random order, but that is another chapter to solve.

Answer (score 0):

For the case 1 : you can use LINQ.

```
var transformedItems = items.Select(item => String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
                                     item.serialno, 
                                     Environment.NewLine, 
                                     item.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ledger name and Group name you can do a query like that:

```
Select coalesce( o.ledger_name ,c.group_name) as result 
From Group_names c JOIN
ledger_names o on o.id_group=c.id_group
group by group_name, ledger_name
with rollup
order by group_name,ledger_name asc
```

alternatively you can use a cursor to create another table reading the tables row by row or you can use a hierarchical grid view such the one used in this links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28276/DataGridView-with-hierarchical-data-binding

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/markrideout/2006/01/08/customizing-the-datagridview-to-support-expandingcollapsing-ala-treegridview/